# What is bash_profile_common?

Tags: terminal, macos

I'm completely new to mac and I was wondering if `~/.bash_profile_common` (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/simonjwright/distributing-gcc/releases) in the *Install* paragraph)  is the same thing as `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: I'm not a Mac user, but I've used bash as my main shell for some 18 years or so, but I've not encountered something called `bash_profile_common`, I think. Could you give us a bit of context to let us know where that appears?

Comment: Same here, 10+ years and never heard of it

Comment: I'm trying to install gcc 12.2.0 (arch64) by simonjwright on a M1 macbook and the installation guide refers to ~/.bash_profile_common but on my macbook there is only a bash_profile

Comment: Probably some this party bash scripting framework that whoever that happens to be has installed. I think all the large and easy to install software managers - macports, homebrew and anaconda (the latter definitely) ship GCC 12.2. what's wrong with using these?

Comment: In MacOS 10.15 Catalina and newer, the default shell is `zsh` instead of `bash`, so on a M1 macbook (which is only supported by MacOS 11 or newer), you probably want to add the suggested `export PATH=/opt/gcc-12.2.0-aarch64/bin:$PATH` into your `~/.zshrc` instead anyway.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help! I think i solved it now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard file for any common default Bash installation, including MacOS.

*Perhaps* the intent is to hint that this code should be `source`d both from `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`; but we can only speculate.

Comment: https://github.com/kwpeters/bash-config contains a file with a similar name, but it appears to be just a personal config.

Comment: Ditto https://github.com/bashonregardless/dotfiles

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545556/gnatmake-compilation-returns-a-255-exit-status-error-what-should-i-do seems to be about a vaguely similar problem.

Comment: Thanks! This was useful.